# limiting characters printed for loop

Tags: python

It's pretty much the "bizz buzz" thing, although I want to make it print 10 words or numbers per line, and also in a similar program allow the user to input the range, and set the amount of words or numbers to print per line

```
for i in range (1,121):
   if i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0 and i%7 == 0:
      print("zipzapzop") 
   elif i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0:
      print("zipzap")
   elif i%3 == 0 and i%7 == 0:
      print("zipzop")
   elif i%3 == 0:
      print("zip")
   elif i%5 == 0:
      print("zap")
   elif i%7 == 0:
      print("zop")   
   else:
      print(i)
```

output:

```
 1
2
zip
4
zap
zip
zop
8
zip
zap
11
zip
13
zop
zipzap
16
17
zip
19
zap
zipzop
22
23
zip
zap
26
zip
zop
29
zipzap
31
32
zip
34
zap
zip
37
38
zip
zap
41
zipzop
43
44
zipzap
46
47
zip
zop
zap
zip
52
53
zip
zap
zop
zip
58
59
zipzap
61
62
zipzop
64
zap
zip
67
68
zip
zap
71
zip
73
74
zipzap
76
zop
zip
79
zap
zip
82
83
zipzop
zap
86
zip
88
89
zipzap
zop
92
zip
94
zap
zip
97
zop
zip
zap
101
zip
103
104
zipzapzop
106
107
zip
109
zap
zip
zop
113
zip
zap
116
zip
118
zop
zipzap
```

this is my output, but I want to make it print 10 numbers or words per line. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the if block you need to do

```
# bump number count
count += 1
# every 10 print a new line 
if count % 10 == 0
        print('')
```

Then you need to disable the newline from printing out normally.  How you do this depends on which version of python you are using.  If you are on 2.7.X you would use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

then you would change your prints to be like

```
print('zipzap',end=' ')
```

Comment: so set count before my for statement, and include count+1 and if count % 10 == 0
        print('') under every if- elif?

Comment: I would put the `count +=1` after your final `else` (and only once), at the same indentation of the original `if`